# ScrollView to disappear before the top of the screen

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I have a scrollview that I want to have disappear as it scrolls across a certain point on the screen. So as you scroll, the elements on the scrollview will disappear instead of covering up the elements behind it. But if you scroll back down, it reappears.  How can I set a point on the screen that will hide the scrollview once it hits that point? I would like to accomplish this without having it "hide" behind another object. Thanks.

Almost forgot, it's all code, no IB used.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the scrollView's `clipsToBounds` property to true?

Or, if that's not what you're trying to do, you'll need to intercept the `scrollViewDidScroll:` method and use the `contentOffset` of the scrollView to determine a threshold at which to make it (or its contents) disappear.

Comment: clipsToBounds didn't work. Trying to figure out the contentOffset thing as we speak.

Answer (score 0):

It's late in the day, these things happen. All I had to do was set the scrollview to proper size and location on the screen and it works great. Setting the ScrollView to the proper x and y and width and height fixed the issue. The upper edge makes the elements disappear when they pass the edge. Thanks again for the help, I'm going to figure out the contentOffset as I'm sure it will be needed one day.